# change_scene_to_file successfully transitions scene, then transports back to the previous scene

Tags: godot, godot-4

I'm having a problem with `change_scene_to_file` in Godot 4. For some reason
after the scene transition succeeded, I was automatically transported back the previous play state.

Here is the video of my problem : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oC1mx1tqMEnfH9ovZAjP_d6DI60xODji/view?usp=sharing

I use the same code for `change_scene`

from inside the house to outside:

```
extends Area2D

var entered = false

func _on_body_entered(_body):
    entered = true

func _on_body_exited(_body):
    entered = false
    
func _process(_delta):
    if entered == true:
        if Input.get_action_strength("enter"):
            get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://Levels/game_level.tscn")
```

from outside to inside the house:

```
extends Area2D

var entered = false

func _on_body_entered(_body):
    entered = true

func _on_body_exited(_body):
    entered = false
    
func _process(_delta):
    if entered == true:
        if Input.get_action_strength("enter"):
            get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://Levels/inside_house.tscn")
```

If I go from `inside_house` to outside it works just fine,
but the other way it starts to have this problem.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is it possible that when you enter the house, you're still standing in the trigger area for the exit door, and the button to activate the door is still pressed? You might need to detect only new presses this frame, or move your spawn position/trigger area apart to break the cycle.

Comment: at first I thought that too, so I then drag the character out, far away from the trigger area, I aIso scaIe down the coIIision shape, but then the probIem stiII remain the same I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for user input in `_process()`, which is executed every frame. It's possible that the interaction key is *not* released before reading user input during the next frame (when you're in the indoor scene). Therefore, the undesired transition takes place as well, taking you back outdoor.

Try to detect the key press only for the current frame by using [`Input.is_action_just_pressed()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-is-action-just-pressed) rather than `Input.get_action_strength()`.